# Studio XPS 16 Fn key does not work

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, drivers, dell-xps, fn-key

I had Vista on my laptop. After a Windows 7 clean install Fn key does not work. For example Fn+1 should be equal to Numpad1 but it does nothing. I have installed several drivers from Dell website but none helped.

Comment: Did you install the Vista keyboard drivers or hotkey software? For all intents and purposes, they should work just fine.

Comment: I have installed Windows 7. So I should look for Windows 7 drivers. The problem is I can not find any :(

Comment: Ok, I'm going to repeat myself: the Vista drivers should work as well, so have you tried them? If the answer is "no", then give them a go. You may be surprised.

Comment: Thanks for following up. But as I have said my problem is I can not find any keyboard drivers either for Vista or Windows 7 on dell.com.